# Tagging audio-files with data from spreadsheet

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix, audio

I have in my music library all the recorded music by the beatles divided into album directories. most of it is *.flac. When I open the files in a music player (rhythmbox on Linux.Ubuntu.14.04). I would like to write a simple bash loop to set the composer tag according to a spreadsheet with all the data extracted from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_recorded_by_the_Beatles
So I can create a *.csv or *.tsv file from there.

I've also learned so far how to use a package called `flac` (`sudo apt-get install flac`) and the command `metaflac`.
Unfortunately, I don't have any expirience in writing loops but I know it should look pretty much like this:

```
for{all files in the current directory}do
 metaflac --remove-tag=composer
done
for{untill reaching the end of file "The-Beatles.db.tsv"}do
 {locate file named as in left part of line x}
 metaflac --set-tag=composer=${right part of line x in file "The-Beatles.db.tsv"}
done
```

Comment: I don't think vim is the tool you're looking. Maybe a tool like [id3v2](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/id3v2) or [eyed3](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/eyed3) would be more interesting to use in a script.

Comment: I've learned how to use id3v2 and eyeD3, they are very useful for *.mp3 but not for *.flac. If I change a tag in a certain *.flac file this tag doesn't seem to change when I view the file in the rhythmbox music player. Any suggestions?

Comment: I never did it by myself, a quick Google search points me to [flack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flack/)  but I'm not sure you can use it non-interactively in a script. My point that to make you notice that you'd need a non-interactive tool and not vim :-) maybe you'll find the tool you need thanks to [software recommendation](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AnhIblgyA8yXRo-s5_zBpYEtgyFtkgqnLw_6eP5grMI/edit?usp=sharing
# URL above is the source of the .tsv file located in the same folder of this script
# **I've copied all the first 2 columns of the spreadsheet to "songs-composers.tsv"**

while read line; do
 IFS=$'\t'
 val=($(echo "$line"))
 # "${val[0]}" is the name of the song
 # "${val[1]}" is the name of the composer
 echo locating song: "${val[0]}"...
  IFS=$'\n'
 file=($(find -iname ""${val[0]}"*.flac"))
 echo "located files are:"
 for j in `seq 1 "${#file[@]}"`; do
  echo "    "${file[$((j-1))]}""
 done
 for j in `seq 1 "${#file[@]}"`; do # for every string in the array 'file'
  echo removing composer-tag for file:        "${file[$((j-1))]}"
  metaflac --remove-tag=composer "${file[$((j-1))]}"
  echo setting-up correct composer-tag as     "${val[1]}"
  metaflac --set-tag=COMPOSER="${val[1]}" "${file[$((j-1))]}"
 done
done < "songs-composers.tsv"
```

Comment: It hardly makes sense to dump the entire database here. The actual script seems to be spending the better part of its time pointnessly changing directories back and forth.

Comment: You are totally right @tripleee, I've edited the script so I hope you will find the new one much more efficient.

Comment: Much better, yes; but why do you need to read the entire TSV into memory?  Is there a reason you can't just read one entry at a time, process that, and forget it, then proceed to the next entry?

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement @tripleee, I have managed to improve the script so it runs over more files than before (in the previous script it 'missed' some files because the names of the songs in the spreadsheet were not identical to the files on my system) anyway I hope you'll find it good enough and vote up for my answer so I'll get reputation ;)